# Check all sent and received mails from my system

Tags: windows, windows-xp, email

I want to know can I configure my mail account (any mail account) with my system IP so that I can **check all sent and received mails from my system** with different users on different mail accounts.

My aim is to see each mail that is sent or received from my system with *any* mail account. If anyone uses my system and sends or receives mail with their account, then I want to see the details of this mail.

Is there any possibility to create such a kind of configuration? Or is there any software that maintains this architecture?

Comment: Your question is not clear: do you want to intercept all mail traffic on your machine?

Comment: yes, some thing like this

Comment: Then please edit your question and make this clear

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can change the clients configuration and that all the accounts are your accounts (i.e., you are not trying to sniff someone else mail).

Outgoing:

You can configure all the accounts to use the local machine as an SMTP relay and then forward all the emails to a second account.

Incoming:

You could configure your machine with something like fetchmail to have a central repository of fetched mail

Comment: how I can configure all accounts using SMTP relay. Please tell.

Comment: You should first install an SMTP server on your machine but this depends on the OS you are using.

Comment: I am using xp profession version 2002 SP2

Comment: Ok I retagged your question. I have no experience with Windows.